# copy files to remote machine's /etc/systemd/ directory using ansible

Tags: ansible

I an new to ansible. I may be saying something which is completely wrong.

I created VM using KVM, both remote and local are running on Ubuntu 16.0.4

Now I configured ansible by creating a key as
ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C "D...@192.168.111.113"
this created key and copied it to remote machine by 
ssh-copy-id D...@192.168.111.113
now I tested ssh is working, it is working fine.

I added remote machine's address in /etc/ansible/hosts under [DDAS] group.

now I can ping to remote machine using ansible. Then I wrote Playbook to copy file. I is working fine to copy files to /home/Das1/ only. I mean, I can copy files to location which do not need root permission.

I want to copy these files to /etc/systemd/ directory instead of the /home/das1/. I changed dest in playbook but it gives permission related errors.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Thank
DAS

Answer (score 1):

By default your playbook tasks execute under the context of the user you use to connect to the remote system. Ansible allows you to [change the user](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/become.html) you use to run a playbook or individual tasks. You can create a new user and give it privileges to the directory you mention or you can use the built-in root user.

To run your entire playbook as root for example put this at the top adjusting for whatever your actual hosts value is:

```
- hosts: 192.168.111.113
  become: true
  become_user: root

  tasks:
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably the /etc/systemd/ directory does not have "write" privilege for the user you are using.

check the permission for /etc/systemd/ with ls -lrt.